# Ajax post for django form not working

Tags: django, jquery

For some reason I cannot get a successful post when trying to use ajax. The code I am trying is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/MRKNq/11/

```
$('#register_form').submit(function(e) {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/echo/json/",
    data: $('#register_form').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.text);
        $('#result').text(data.text);
    },
    type: 'POST'
});


e.preventDefault();

});​
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this just in jsfiddle or is it from an actual webpage? http://jsfiddle.net/MRKNq/19/

Comment: The form is the same one that I have on the page. The jquery and <scripts> are things I was trying out on jsfiddle.

Comment: The thing I cant figure out, is how to post the data, and either display results saying that a user already exists, or complete the submit if successful.

Comment: have you tried to post back data without ajax ?

Comment: As it stands at the moment, without ajax I can authenticate just fine, however if there is an error the page just reloads with username in the form filled in. To give a bigger picture. I have a dialog box that displays the login form. If I click submit, the form closes, even if the post fails. I am trying to use ajax to pause the submit, then post/validate the data, and return the results by either displaying an error message, or closing the dialog box upon success.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the response that comes back in Firebug or some other tool. This likely has to do with CSRF.

Have a look at this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

You can also exempt your view from CSRF protection by using this decorator: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt

Comment: I have that enabled csrf enabled in the js file. That's not the issue. I am not getting any errors in console. I get a 200 response and nothing happens.